# Elasticsearch JDBC River 3000 document limit

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, elasticsearch

I'm tinkering with elasticsearch as a trial for doing some reporting on one of my servers.  It set up fine and what I'm wanting to do is have ES consume a SQLServer table for trying out some aggregate reporting.  The table I'm pulling from has over 100k records, but it seems to only be pulling 3000.

I'm defining my river as simply this:

```
{
"type":"jdbc",
"jdbc": {
    "driver":"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver", 
    "url":"jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=Uzbekistan",
    "user":"username","password":"******",
    "index":"tstFlattened",
    "type":"test",
    "sql":"select * from vwTest",
    "poll":"30s"
}

}
```

The index seems to create ok, the fields and data are pulled correctly, but it's only grabbing 3000 records.  There are 5 shards created, but I have tried adding other settings to expands the number of shards used for the index and it seems to only create 5.

Has anyone encountered this?  Is there something I missed in setup that limits documents per shard?  I thought it was supposed to be up to 2^32 docs per shard, but I'm sure I'm missing something as I'm an ES newb

Comment: This likely a JDBC river issue, not something internal to ES. Can you share your sql schema and some sample data?

Comment: unfortunately in this case I cannot because the data in that table and even the structure of it is sensitive to our company operations.  Sorry, but hopefully someone has an idea about the general river config.

Comment: Just to note, I am using the latest jdbc river plugin.